# How can I implement HttpMethod (HttpMethodNameActionInterface) for ActionInterface in a controller?

Tags: controllers, magento2.4, interface, actioninterface

This class `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` is deprecated:

- What is the interface to be implemented in the controller action?
- How should I implement the interface in the controller action?
- What should the controller structure with the implemented interface look like?

**Below is this warning that identifies with the implementation of the Action Interface.**

> The class VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Routing\ControllerAction does not restrict processed HTTP methods by implementing a HttpMethod nameActionInterface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Action class with `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface`
- In the example below you can see how it is implemented with the structure.

Example:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory;

/**
 * Class Index
 */
class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ForwardFactory
     */
    private $forwardFactory;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     * @param ForwardFactory $forwardFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ForwardFactory $forwardFactory
    ) {
        $this->forwardFactory = $forwardFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var Forward $forward */
        $forward = $this->forwardFactory->create();
        return $forward->forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }
}
```

[Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html) is the Magento documentation on Routing and Action Class ([ActionInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ActionInterface.php))